# Cannot Fix a header above RecyclerView in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I need to show a header above a RecyclerView but with the code below, the header is not fixed and gets scrolled with the recycler view.
Does anyone has a solution for his problem?

---

### **fragment_history_detail.xml**

[[**First Try**]]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <include
            layout="@layout/view_header_history_detail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/header_container">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView_history_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
            tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_history_detail_item_self" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[[**Second Try**]]

I also tried using LinearLayout like below. But it doesn't help.

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        layout="@layout/view_header_history_detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView_history_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_history_detail_item_self" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[[**Third Try**]]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        layout="@layout/view_header_history_detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView_history_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
            tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_history_detail_item_self" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

### **view_header_history_detail.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_back"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/title_height"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/vector_expand_left" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/title_height"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="History Detail"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="?attr/colorHeaderText"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`. And ser `Orientation` to `vertical`. So that the layout place top to bottom.

So, Your parent layout should be link this ->

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground">

        <!--Your child layouts goes here-->


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment but it still doesn't solve my problem. The header keeps getting scrolled down.

Comment: If i change the RecyclerView with a ListView, the header does not get scrolled. But I have to use a RecyclerView.

Comment: Can you try by removing the `layout_weight` from the `RecyclerView`

Comment: Yes I did try by removing layout_weight from RecyclerView. No change ! :(

Comment: Can you share code of this layout `view_header_history_detail` ?

Comment: OK i added the view_header_history_detail.xml as well. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Copy below code and put in your xml file

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/header_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <include
        layout="@layout/view_header_history_detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/header_container">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView_history_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_history_detail_item_self" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

remove above relative layout or you can paste ralative layout content

```
<RelativeLayout
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView_history_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_history_detail_item_self" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You use LinearLayout  and set Orientation to vertical and then put above code into that <LinearLayout >paste here above code</LinearLayout  >

Comment: Thank you but i did exactly as you said. But the above header keeps scrolling and doesn't get fixed at the top. I have updated the code i tried. Please check the above CODE.([[THIRD TRY]])

Answer (score 0):

if you want to fix the layout then u can do one thing as i m thinking....
look the code below....

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include
    layout="@layout/view_header_history_detail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<RelativeLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView_history_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_history_detail_item_self" /></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yes I did try the way you said. The code i tried is above [[Third TRY]]. Still the header is not fixed and gets scrolled by the RecyclerView.

Comment: can u post the video of ur problem... so i cn batter understand

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. it works for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include layout="@layout/view_header_history_detail" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerChat"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried but again unsuccessful to fix this problem. But one thins is really troubling me is that, when i fix the height like "250dp" or something, then the header gets fixed and doesn't get scrolled. But if i use "wrap_content" again the header gets scrolled with the RecyclerView.

Comment: In your view_header_history_detail.xml file, make linear layout height to "wrap_content" instead of "match_parent". Also, make sure you don't specify height/width while including layout. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I did that too, and still had the problem so i simply changed RecyclerView to a ListView for now.